# Arduino: Lists? Or equivalent

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to make an array of colours but unfortunatly Tinker library doesnt seem to support Arrays:

```
Tinker::Vect3d<float> rndCol[5];

rndCol[0] = {255,0,0};
rndCol[1] = {0,255,0};
rndCol[2] = {0,0,255};
rndCol[3] = {255,165,0};
rndCol[4] = {5,125,200};
```

.

```
soundLvel:47: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '=' token
soundLvel:48: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '=' token
soundLvel:49: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '=' token
soundLvel:50: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '=' token
soundLvel:51: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '=' token
```

So does Arduino support lists or equivalent I can store these in. I cant find anything in the reference.

Answer (score 3):

You can just create a 2D array to store your RGB colour values:

```
int colourArray[5][3] =
{
  {255,0,0},
  {0,255,0},
  {0,0,255},
  {255,165,0},
  {5,125,200}
};
```

Note that the 5 in `[5][3]` is optional, if omitted (`[][3]`) it will automatically be assigned to the number of elements you initialise.

You can only access one element at a time though, so you will need to loop through the 3 RGB sub elements if you want to assign them to some other array. Eg:

```
int some_colour[3];
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    some_colour[i] = colourArray[2][i];
}
```